# How to block database from .accdb file

Tags: java, ms-access

I used a .accdb file as database to my Java desktop application. This file works as database but I can also open it and see the all data and I can also change it never use the program. There is some way to block the file and the user can't open the file directly with Access?

Comment: No, but you can encrypt it with a password.

Comment: @Gustav, how can I set the password?

Comment: You can set it with Microsoft Access. Don't know about Java options. I don't do Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open MS Access
2. Click File, Then Open
3. Browse out to the DB IN FILE EXPLORER
4. Click the arrow beside the open button, choose the option that says open exclusive
5. Next go to Info, then select the encrypt with password option

Comment: Just warning you though, if someone really wanted to break into your Access database, they could find an online tool to crack the database's password. It's not full proof but, it will at least hinder just anyone from messing around with your database.

Comment: From the looks of it OP doesn't seem to care about this issue. Hes probably using a Java based client on another computer that does not have direct access to the PC. Security of the Physical PC is an entirely a different issue. But good point though.